# How do I apply spearman rank correlation on one continuous variables like sales data in and other discrete variable like Industries count?

Tags: correlation, spearman-rho, association-measure

I have a dataframe with total sales of around 500 product categories in each row. So there are 500 columns in my dataframe. I am trying to find the highest correlated category with my another dataset columns. Data is not normalized and highly skewed.

> I want to divide my sales into some buckets on the basis of a range of sales value. I will also divide other dataset with which I will find correlation into buckects.Can I use spearman rank correlation this way? Since Spearman can only be applied to ordinal data.
>
> > Also, Is this the correct approach for my problem statement to find highly correlated categories? I have already tried Pearson correlation, but I want to compare my results with Spearman method.

Comment: Is there something wrong with comparing them column by column using Spearman correlation?

Comment: 1. counts are not continuous; they're discrete. 2. Why would you bin your variables (place them into buckets?) -- that seems quite counterproductive.

Comment: @Glen_b spearman method takes only ordinal values. So I need to give some rank to my sales data? or I can simply pass the continuous values in the python spearman function?

Comment: @Dave Can I simply pass a continuous variable and a discrete variable in spearman function? As it works with ordinal values, like rank based values

Comment: @PriyankaSharma Your assertion is incorrect (I'd appreciate if you could mention which source gives you this mistaken idea). It is actually designed to work with numeric (interval and ratio on Stevens' typology) data, which are then ranked in the calculation. It *can* be extended to be used with ordinal values, but they are then re-ranked in the calculation,  and special effort has to be taken to properly handle the ensuing ties.

Comment: Indeed Spearman's original calculation is based on there being no ties. He assumes a situation where the presence of ties will make little difference (he discusses the case of a single tie in a footnote). It will only be true if there are hardly any ties, which is not the case with binned data unless there are so many bins that almost all observations are in their own bin.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks Glen for detailed explanation. I am refering wiki as main source of information. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient  I misunderstood the concept may be. So I can directly pass on my data to python's spearman function? No modification of data should be done before using this function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111275/discussion-between-priyanka-sharma-and-glen-b).

Comment: No modification of the data need be done, nor should it.

Comment: what is your "another " data set . and why do you want it  correlate?

Comment: @SubhashC.Davar My another dataset is Different types of industries count in every county like manufacturing, construction etc. I want to find out if the count of industries has any correlation with my product category wise sales.